# ASP.NET mvc Return User to the page if he didn't click "end session"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, session, controller, action

I'm working on an end-project for school. I have the following question: the goal is to return the last user to the page if he didn't click on "End Session". I'm using StartDate and EndDate in my controller. I have no idea how to use EndDate value to redirect the user to the page, along as he didn't click on "End Session".

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to logout user you should just add server check when user will perform any new action he will be logged out. If you need client side - you need to add timeout on page load. If You have end date/time and current in browser you can get diff and schedule timer  for this. On timer trigger you can remove all data and show login screen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but  I have a different problem here is what im trying to do: A user enters a page to count birds, when he clicks on "Start New Counting" he enters a "counting page"( StartDate=DateTime.Now) has been added. If user clicks "Stop Counting", then he leaves that page(EndDate=DateTime.Now) has been added. But, if the user didn't click on "Stop Counting" and leaves the application, he should come back on the "counting page". What should I do to make user come back on "counting page" after he has been logged in?

Comment: Do you have any mechanism of user identification?

Comment: Logged in mean that we can differentiate users. Yes ?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you need to store state some where.

If your (lets call it wizard) is processing on client and you need to restore client at specific wizard step the only way I can see is using localStorage.

If your data is send on each step - just add stage information in your DB and send this info to the client in each wizard start request

Comment: OK, I will try it. Thanks